# React D3 component did not get unmounted upon (component) redirect using history.push()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, d3.js

React D3 component did not get unmounted upon (component) redirect using the following approach. That is, in a SPA, while on 'graphA', clicking a button redirects to 'graphB'. 'graphB' is rendered, however, 'graphA' is still visible. Thoughts on how I can remove/unmount 'graphA' such that only 'graphB' is visible. I tried calling `ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode()` in various React lifecycle hooks with no success.

```
this.props.history.push({ pathname: '/graphB' })
```

Comment: Have you tried using a `<Switch>` component?

Comment: What router are you using? If you do use a <Switch /> from react-router like @Colin mentioned this wouldn't happen unless you have the match pattern wrong.

Comment: And to be fair, the amount of information that's lacking in your question makes this nearly impossible to assist with.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using React Router, this is how to use a `Switch` component. It will render the component for the first path that matches.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';

const A = () => <h1>A</h1>
const B = () => <h1>B</h1>

const Landing = ({ history }) => {
  const goToA = () => {
    history.push('a');
  }

  const goToB = () => {
    history.push('b');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={goToA}>Go to A</button>
      <button onClick={goToB}>Go to B</button>
    </div>
  )
}

const App = ({ history }) => {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
      <Route path="/a" component={A} />
      <Route path="/a" component={A} />
    </Switch>
  )
}
render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>
  , document.getElementById('root'));
```

Live example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rr-switch-example?file=index.js).

Comment: Sorry, I changed the URL. Try the link now.